# Getting an IllegalArgumentException while adding line data

Tags: android, mpandroidchart, illegalargumentexception

When more than some datasets (around 6 or more) to a line graph, we are getting an exception.
This is the detail:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: One or more of the DataSet Entry arrays are longer than the x-values array of this ChartData object.
 at com.github.mikephil.charting.data.ChartData.isLegal(ChartData.java:173)
 at com.github.mikephil.charting.data.ChartData.init(ChartData.java:130)
 at com.github.mikephil.charting.data.ChartData.<init>(ChartData.java:96)
 at com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarLineScatterCandleData.<init>(BarLineScatterCandleData.java:27)
 at com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineData.<init>(LineData.java:27)
```

I am not able to understand the reason why.
I am using MPAndroidChart to plot the graph.
When more data sets are entered, we are getting that exception.

Comment: The error is quite clear: you have more elements in DataSet than the ones in the x-values. Please post your code if you want others to be able to help you.

Answer (score 7):

The error is exactly as explained. Heres it visually in case its a language barrier

............................---------------------------

Chart  .................|. 1 ... 2 ... 3 ... 4 ... 5 .|

Data Set 1 .........|. a ... b ... c ... d ... e .|

Data Set 2 .........|. a ... b ... c ... d ... e .|

Data Set 3 .........|. a ... b ... c ... d ... e .|

Data Set 4 .........|. a ... b ... c ... d ... e .|

Data Set 5 .........|. a ... b ... c ... d ... e .|

Data Set 6 .........|. a ... b ... c ... d ... e .|

Data Set 7 .........|. a ... b ... c ... d ... e .|... f ... g

............................---------------------------

As you can see the last data set has too many items to fit into the chart so the app does not know how to handle it and throws an error